# I have lost partition table for my USB Flash drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, gparted

I working on Ubuntu 11.10 I have used GParted for formatting my pendrive (2 GB) but unfortunately I have lost the partition table for it. I unable create it using GParted .
How do I create a new partition table?

Comment: You need to be a little more specific.  Why are you unable to create a new partition table with gparted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to restore it with testdisk. Testdisk is in the Ubuntu repositories, install it with software center or apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Testdisk is a command line utility, there is a step-by-step guide (with pictures) here

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step